# rewrite line in SdFat for arduino

Tags: arduino

My problem is that I am trying to make Controller using Arduino, ESP8266 SDcard module and some sensors. When I try to store some data in SDcard, at first time all works fine, but in second or third time I need to rewrite same line with different values. But there is an issue because line length is not equal with previous. 
If it is longer then nothing wrong, but if shorter, then it will leave some unnecessary characters.
The most difficult part is where I need to store value of LED light and time:
255 10 0 Where 255 represents LED-value, 10-Hour, 0-min
Value can be 1 or 3 character long, hour 1 or 2, min 1 or 2...

So is there any solutions for this problem??

Now I am trying to change int to uint8_t to equal all possible values.
Is this approach Right? Maybe someone has made something like that?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize the data as you suggest so that the line length is always the same.

One approach is that all values are `uint8_t` which would require 3 uint8_t values.

Another is leave it as a string but each field is a fixed width with padded values. e.g. `0050901` for a value 5 at the 9th hour, 1st minute. Or pad with spaces so   `5 9 1` for the same representation of this data. (Two spaces before the 5 and one space before the 9 and the 1).

Either approach is fine and just depends on what you prefer or what is easier when consuming and/or writing the data.